# Visual Studio 2015 missing .Net Providers for OleDb

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, ole

I have Visual Studio 2015 installed. In the SSIS Packages, within the Connection Manager, I am creating a new OLE DB Connection.

However, under provider, I am only seeing a option for Native OLE DB:

[image]

What I am hoping to see is .Net Providers for OleDb:

[image]

Any ideas why this is missing? I've checked a number of articles online, installed various extensions/add-ons, yet nothing. Always missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to choose the `ADO.NET` instead of `OLEDB`.

[image]

Then you can find the `.Net Providers` for OleDb there.

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ah! Guess it had nothing to do with the extensions and I was just being silly.